# How to tell if an actionevent has been performed for an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, awt, actionevent

I need to know if a specific action event has been performed because in the if statement I will have another action be performed, but it depends on which action event(s) have already been performed.

```
xButton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x9) {
                xButton9.setVisible(false);
                oButton9.setVisible(false);
                nine.repaint();
                nine.add(xlabel);
        }
} );

oButton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o9) {
                xButton9.setVisible(false);
                oButton9.setVisible(false);
                nine.repaint();
                nine.add(olabel);
        }      
} );  

if (ActionEvent 09 has been performed) {
    do this stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle that inside of your `actionPerformed()` method, while you still have a reference to `o9`.

```
oButton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o9) {
    xButton9.setVisible(false);
    oButton9.setVisible(false);
    nine.repaint();
    nine.add(olabel);

    // whatever else happens when oButton9 is clicked
    }      
} );
```

Comment: but what happens when oButton9 is clicked depends on if other buttons have been clicked previously, would there be a way to write an if statement that checks the visibility of oButton9 because of the fact that the visibility is set to false in the actionevent?

Comment: I see -- you'd have to keep track of button states yourself (i.e. which ones have been pressed already) in your class.